# How to create an procedual 3D brick texture for displacemnet modifier

Tags: modeling, texturing, materials

Hey guys I am new to blender. I want to use it in the first place to create and shape models for 3D prnting. My first project is a castle. I want to start easy and decided to make an easy wall with an 3D brick texture. I managed to apply a 3D brick texture on one face of my wall by watching some tutorials on youtube.
Now I am looking for a possibility to create a procedual brick texture for the displacement and to put the texture only on certain faces of the wall.
If somebody has an idea or solution for this, it would be wonderful.

Comment: Bake the texture to an image --> apply with the displacement modifier wherever you like.

Comment: Displacement is a very inefficient way of modeling a whole castle full of bricks, you will need a ton of needless geometry for this to work and look anywhere near presentable.